# Conditioning over list element in Data Frame columns

Tags: python, pandas

Getting data from API, and for one item there is lots of data so I decided to put them into a List. Now I have Data Frame with a column containing `List` elements. I want to write a function which is checking some conditions, e.g. who is the best based on ability and stats. Something like `whoIsTheBest('fire-punch', 'speed')`, where fire-punch is in "move" column, and speed value in "speed" column (it has most speed and can do that "move").

I have an issue accessing elements List elements from a column "move". This is how I fetched the data:

```
for x in elements:
    url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/" + str(x["entry_number"]) + "/"
    get_pokemon = requests.get(url)
    get_pokemon_json = get_pokemon.json()
    d = {'id': x["entry_number"], 
         'name': x["pokemon_species"]["name"],
         'special_defense': get_pokemon_json["stats"][1]["base_stat"],
         'special_attack': get_pokemon_json["stats"][2]["base_stat"],
         'defense': get_pokemon_json["stats"][3]["base_stat"],
         'attack': get_pokemon_json["stats"][4]["base_stat"],
         'hp': get_pokemon_json["stats"][5]["base_stat"],
         'move': list(y['move']['name'] for y in get_pokemon_json['moves']),
         'type': list(z['type']['name'] for z in get_pokemon_json['types'])
        }  
    all_data.append(d)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(all_data)



             move        name  \
0    [razor-wind, swords-dance, cut, bind, vine-whi...   bulbasaur   
1    [swords-dance, cut, bind, vine-whip, headbutt,...     ivysaur
```

Tried with the following:

```
if 'fire-punch' in str(df1["move"]):
```

but getting `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

Is there maybe better approach for creating column values instead of List or is there some way I can access each element? And is there a reason that elements are in `[]` parentheses?

Answer (score 1):

df1["move"] is a column and has a set of values (can be considered Series as per pandas). So its not a string. Thats throwing the error.

Instead you can check it like this:

```
for item in df1.move.values:
   if 'fire-punch' in item:
       print("Yes, its found in: ", item)
```

Also, I see each row is a `list` in this case.

Comment: Tried if 'fire-punch' in df1.move.values: print(df1.move.values), nothing is happening

Comment: Manually, You checked if 'fire-punch' is present in df1["move"] column?

Comment: Yes, there is 'fire-punch' in like 50 rows

Comment: Ok, I am fixing it

Comment: Edited my answer. The fix was, as it is a list, it has to be iterated one more level before the conditional validation. Check and upvote if it works for you.

Comment: it's printing all lines that contains value, how can i print only names base od the condition?